# Copying inherited directories containing symlinks

Tags: php, bash, symlink

This is similar to questions that have been asked before, but I promise it is different.

I have a site that involves inheritance from a parent to a child site. Part of this is media. To make media serve faster, I am creating a symlink-ed copy of the parent directory in the child, then override those with any files the child specifically defines. This allows apache to serve statically from the media (which may come from a parent) while inheriting html form the parent.

Example after build where inheritance is common->maps->cars :

```
/some/directory/common/
   images/
      cats.png
      muffins.png
   css/
      styles.css

/some/directory/maps/
   images/
      cats.png -> /some/directory/common/images/cats.png
      muffins.png (overridden by child)
   css/
      styles.css -> /some/directory/common/css/styles.css
      mapsStyles.css (child only)

/some/directory/cars/
   images/
      cats.png -> /some/directory/common/images/cats.png
      muffins.png -> /some/directory/maps/images/muffins.png
   css/
      styles.css -> /some/directory/common/css/styles.css
      carsStyles.css (child only)
```

So I could symlink to `/images/muffins.png` and receive the correct media based on the site that I'm on. The site-specific media is stored in the same directory structure, but in a different location only containing media specific to that site.

The issue is that no matter how I try to do it, the second child ends up with a symlink to its parent, not the originator. In the example above, I cannot get `/some/direcory/cars/images/cats.png` to point to the common media programatically, only the maps media.

Currently I am using the command `cp -sR /some/directory/maps/* /some/directory/cars/`

I'm running this on PHP, but currently using `cp` and `ln` commands in the PHP `exec()` function to build these structures.

Comment: Just browsing the questino without actually taking the time to grok it : it sounds like a time to use `tar` (with proper options about symlinks, depending on the need) instead of `cp` ...

Comment: So you want to make symlinks to the parent, UNLESS the parent already contains a symlink, then it should be a symlink to the original?

Comment: Correct, Barmar. Otherwise, I will get too many levels of symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should use `tar` and not `cp` :
please try (I can't test it right now; watch out what *your* versino of tar does by default with symlinks. it should save them as symlinks, not follow them... but ymmv) :

```
#step 1: create an archive of one of the directories_using_common_symlinks:
cd /some/directory/maps/
tar cvf /somewhere/wholeshebang.tar images/ css/
        #ie, tar everything (directories, symlinks, etc).
        #Please add whatever is missing
        #note: it will also contain extra (specific) stuff, which we get rid of below

#step 2: create the real archive of JUST the common stuff
cd /some/temporary_dir/
tar xvf /somewhere/wholeshebang.tar  #regurgitate all the content.
rm      /somewhere/wholeshebang.tar  #we won't need that one anymore, it contains too much
rm images/muffins.png  css/mapStyles.css #delete all extra stuff
tar cvf /somewhere/just_commons.tar  #recreate tar, this time with only common stuff.

#step 3: use the new archive to "kickstart" the other directories
cd /the/destination
tar xvf /somewhere/just_commons.tar  #regurgitte the common stuff (dirs, symlinks)
#then add whatever is specific to /the/destination
```

Comment: I'm checking this out...but it looks promising. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @boerema: I may have not really answered you on the "parent/child" part, but I hope I understood the need underneath ^^ ie, just tar one of the dirs with the most link to the common stuff (or create one, with every links to common stuff), clean it up to only contain the common stuff, and then use it to "kickstart" the new childs... and then replace common links by specific links as needed (and also add whatever is needed)

Comment: Exactly. I'm thinking that your solution to tar up the parent and untar it into the child directory first will preserve the original symlinks, solving my problem.

Comment: @boerema: another interresting approach: step1: create a MD5sum (or sha1) list of files of /some/directory/common : each line containing: "theMD5 /path/to/file".  Step2 : create child. Create another list of "theMD5 /path/of/child/and/file"  Step 3: compare the 2: for every match of MD5; do a proper binary diff, and if they match, replace with a symlink to /path/to/file.   BUT all this (+ the question) assume you never write in your child's files (or it will follow the symlink and change the common file!)

Comment: This ended up being a great approach for what I needed to do

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is just the links ..... you could try "cp -l" .... ( check man cp for more info )

man page :

```
-l, --link
     hard link files instead of copying
```

hence that should resolve this !

Comment: the -s flag does this, it just doesn't create symlinks with the same target as the original. It creates links to the copied symlink. And it is my understanding that -l will make a hard link, not a symlink.

Comment: The -s flag is for symbolic links and the -l flag is for hard links 
man info ::  -s, --symbolic-link
                    make symbolic links instead of copying

Comment: I believe I said in the question that I am making symlinks, not hard links.